# Convertendo colunas em linha concatenando os resultados

Tags: mysql, query, select

Tenho o seguinte select :

```
SELECT pedido, item FROM pedidos
```

Como pego o resultado dele em colunas e passo para linha concatenando com `-`? Exemplo:

> Resultado

```
pedido    item
1         batata
1         arroz
1         feijão
1         tomate
```

> Esperado:

```
pedido   item 
1         batata - arroz - feijão - tomate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)**:

```
SELECT pedido, GROUP_CONCAT(item SEPARATOR ' - ') as item FROM pedidos
```

Teste no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e381c3b/2)**

Comment: Perfeito, Obrigado.